# How to manually install USB3 drivers?

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, usb-3

I tried to copy over my old Bootcamp partition to my new iMac (for those wondering: with sysprep & winclone). So that's working ok. I got to the "first setup my computer screen".

But now I'm facing the keyboard/mouse issue in which I can't use any of these. It seems that the ports are USB3, and the drivers in Win7 are only USB2. So I have to install these, but safe mode doesn't work (I first need to go through the first-time setup), and my keyboard/mouse don't work so I can't install anything either.

Is there some way (I can access the NTFS drive from within my OSX partition), in which I can inject the USB3 drivers so they're loaded up the next time Windows starts?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you  have any USB2 ports?

Comment: @FidelI. Yes of course... it's an iMac. So it has 4 usb ports. But I read somewhere that it is seen as usb3. On my old iMac my keyboard worked fine as I think this was usb2. And win7 only has usb2 support... so I have to manually inject them into the system... but purely on the filesystem basis. And maybe some kind of uni modifications.

Comment: @StevenVanIngelgem - You read incorrectly.

Comment: @Ramhound well. it does not work. And it did work with my old Mac. And a lot of people their issues were solved by adding usb3 drivers into the win7 installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this took me quite some time to figure out, but finally... I have it.
And for all those wondering... It **WAS** a problem with USB3!

What did I do to transfer my data from one iMac to another? Hereby a hopefully step-by-step guide which worked for me.

1. Attach a big usb harddrive to the old iMac.
2. Boot in OSX (ALT at startup)
3. Run Winclone and backup your current configuration (save as image on the big usb harddrive)
4. See that you have a terminal running with "pmset noidle" in there. This prevents your harddrives from sleeping and this process from taking a few days instead of a few hours.
5. After this initial backup finishes, reboot in Windows
6. run sysprep (%windir%/sysprep/sysprep.exe)
7. choose OOBE (out of box experience), check generalize and choose Shutdown. Press OK.
8. Wait for your computer to shut down.
9. Boot up again in OSX. Do NOT let it enter windows!!
10. re-backup your bootcamp partition to another image with Winclone (run pmset to keep it from taking forever).
11. Boot the new machine in OSX.
12. Download [Bootcamp drivers](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1721?locale=nl_BE&viewlocale=nl_NL) on the NEW machine. See that it matches the correct machine you own (otherwise download 5.1.5621).
13. Extract the drivers.
14. Run a pmset-terminal here too.
15. Run the bootcamp assistent and create the new partition (from scratch). Step 14 is important to prevent your machine from auto-restarting.
16. Once the backup finished at the old machine, attach the hdd to the new machine and drag/drop the sysprepped image in winclone. Restore the image to the newly made bootcamp partition.
17. Wait for it to finish.
18. Install NTFS-3G if not already on the new machine (you need to be able to write to the Bootcamp partition) [link with nice explanation](http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/06/how-to-enable-writing-to-ntfs-hard.html)
19. Copy ALL drivers from $WinPEDriver$/IntelxHCISetup/Drivers/HCSwitch/Win7/x64/* and $WinPEDriver$/IntelxHCISetup/Drivers/xHCI/Win7/x64/* to your bootcamp partition under %windir%/inf.
20. let the computer boot into Bootcamp.

I had some issues with services starting up (it didn't want to continue). Seems going once into safe mode (or at least trying to) fixed this and I could continue in normal mode.
So what happened:

- chkdsk ran
- the system rebooted
- the system couldn't start some service
- force computer shut down
- reboot in safe mode (F8)
- the system needs to complete the installation under normal mode
- force computer shut down
- reboot normally
- Everything worked fine.

That's all folks.